# grouped list view in gtk

Tags: gtk

Is there a way to achieve a view in following screenshot by Gtk?

I have tried treeview, but it doesn't automatically filtered out the group.

KDELibs equivalent is KCategorizedView.

[image: example]

Edit:
My use case it like:
for example like the screen shot, if I type Mythology, AOE and AOE III will not be shown, since there is no match under that group.

If I try to use treeview, the parent node not cannot be easily filtered, since the filtermodel cannot easily depends on the filtered result.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't automatically filtered out the group"?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `GtkTreeView` with a `GtkTreeStore`, but there is no stock widget that has the appearance of the KDE widget.

alternatively, you can have different `GtkTreeView` instances, each inside a `GtkFrame` and each using a `GtkTreeModelFilter` to apply a filter to the same `GtkListStore` or `GtkTreeStore`, so that you can keep that data inside a single storage.

the layout would look like:

```
GtkBox
+---- GtkFrame
|     +---- GtkTreeView
|
+---- GtkFrame
|     +---- GtkTreeView
|
+---- GtkFrame
|     +---- GtkTreeView
|
...
```

the `GtkTreeModelFilter` can be set to filter all rows inside the source `GtkListStore` or `GtkTreeStore` that match the "category" you want.

Comment: I updated some about my use case, actually I need that "GtkFrame" to be hide if it's empty, and I have maybe hundreds of group, I don't know create that much widget is a good idea or not.